# R Shiny error - cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny

I know this question has been asked many times before, but none of the solutions that I've read seem to work for me. 
I have an R shiny app that works perfectly on my computer, but when I try to deploy it to an online server, I get the error "cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'". Here is my code (I have it all combined in app.R):

```
ui <- navbarPage(title = 'COVID Tweets',
  tabPanel(
  # App title ----
  title = "US",
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "dateUS",
                  label = "Date:",
                  min = as.Date('2020-01-21'),
                  max = as.Date('2020-05-02'),
                  value = as.Date('2020-03-12'),
                  animate = animationOptions(interval = 2000)
                  ), 
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sentimentUS', 
                   label = 'Sentiment measure', 
                   choices = c('Anxiety' = 'mean_anx', 
                               'Sadness' = 'mean_sad', 
                               'Anger' = 'mean_anger')
                   ),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'covid_measure', 
                   label = 'COVID-19 measure',
                   choices = c('New Cases' = 'new_cases_mean_log10_no0',
                               'New Deaths' = 'new_deaths_mean_log10_no0',
                               '% New Cases' = 'pct_new_cases_mean')
                   )
      ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "my_plot")
    )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    # App title ----
    title = "State",
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
      # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(inputId = "date",
                    label = "Date:",
                    min = as.Date('2020-01-21'),
                    max = as.Date('2020-05-02'),
                    value = as.Date('2020-03-12'),
                    animate = animationOptions(interval = 2000)
        ),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sentiment', 
                   label = 'Sentiment measure', 
                   choices = c('Anxiety' = 'mean_anx', 
                               'Sadness' = 'mean_sad', 
                               'Anger' = 'mean_anger')
      ),
      selectInput(inputId = 'state',
                  label = 'State Spotlight',
                  choices = fips,
                  selected = 36
      ),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'curve_measure', 
                   label = 'COVID-19 measure',
                   choices = c('New Cases' = 'new_cases_mean_curve',
                               'New Deaths' = 'new_deaths_mean_curve',
                               '% New Cases' = 'pct_new_cases_mean_curve')
      )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput(outputId = "state_plot")
      )
    )

                   )
  )



# SERVER FUNCTION ---------------------------------------------------------

server_function <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({

    colorUS <- case_when(input$sentimentUS == 'mean_anx'~'darkorchid3',
                         input$sentimentUS == 'mean_sad'~'dodgerblue3',
                         input$sentimentUS == 'mean_anger'~'firebrick3')

    df_sent <- sentiment_bystate %>% 
      filter(date == input$dateUS,
             input$sentimentUS > 0) %>% 
      select(date, fips, input$sentimentUS)

    li_sent <- c(0,df_sent %>%
                   filter(input$sentimentUS > 0) %>% 
                  pull(input$sentimentUS) %>% max())

    df_covid <- states_df %>% 
      filter(date == input$dateUS) %>% 
      select(date, fips, input$covid_measure)

    li_covid <- c(0,df_covid %>%
      filter(input$covid_measure > 0) %>% 
      pull(input$covid_measure) %>% max())

    # create the plot
      plot_sentiment <- plot_usmap(data = df_sent, 
                                   values = input$sentimentUS) + 
      theme(legend.position = 'right') + 
      scale_fill_continuous(name = 'Sentiment\n(%)',
                            low = 'white',
                            high = colorUS,
                            limits = li_sent) +
        ggtitle('Sentiment Measure') + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                        size = 24),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
              legend.title.align = .5)

      plot_covid <- plot_usmap(data = df_covid,
                               values = input$covid_measure) + 
        theme(legend.position = 'right') + 
        scale_fill_continuous(name = 'Number',
                              low = 'white',
                              high = 'tomato4',
                              limits = li_covid) +
        ggtitle('COVID-19 Measure') + 
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                        size = 24),
              legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
              legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
              legend.title.align = .5)

    # Display the plot
    gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot_sentiment,plot_covid, ncol = 1)

  })

  output$state_plot <- renderPlot({

    color <- case_when(input$sentiment == 'mean_anx'~'darkorchid3',
                         input$sentiment == 'mean_sad'~'dodgerblue3',
                         input$sentiment == 'mean_anger'~'firebrick3')

    df_sentstate <- sentiment_bystate %>% 
      filter(date == input$date,
             fips == input$state) %>% 
      select(date, fips, input$sentiment)

    df_senttime <- sentiment_bystate %>% 
      filter(fips == input$state,
             date >= states_df %>% filter(fips %in% input$state) %>% 
               pull(date) %>% min())

    state_map <- plot_usmap(include = input$state,
                            data = df_sentstate,
                            values = input$sentiment) + 
      scale_fill_continuous(name = input$sentiment,
                            low = 'white',
                            high = color,
                            limits = c(0,sentiment_bystate %>% 
                                         filter(fips == input$state) %>% 
                                         pull(input$sentiment) %>% max())) +
      theme(legend.position = "right")

  state_curve <- ggplot(data = states_df %>% 
                          filter(fips == input$state)) +
    geom_line(aes(x = date, y = states_df %>% 
                    filter(fips == input$state) %>% 
                    pull(input$curve_measure)), color = 'black',size = 2) +
    geom_point(data = df_senttime, 
               aes(x = date, y = df_senttime %>% 
                     pull(input$sentiment)*(states_df %>% 
                                        filter(fips == input$state) %>%
                                        pull(input$curve_measure) %>% max(na.rm = TRUE)/df_senttime 
                                      %>% pull(input$sentiment) %>% max())),
                   color = color, size = 2) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = input$date) +
    labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Severity') +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                    size = 18),
          legend.title = element_text(size = 12))

  gridExtra::grid.arrange(state_map,state_curve,ncol = 1)

  })

})


# SHINY APP CALL --------------------------------------------------------------

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server_function)
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting R on your system before running the app : this will empty memory of any loaded objects that is not loaded on the server

Comment: In the `ui` definition I get `Error in hasGroups(choices) : object 'fips' not found`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I should note that some of the variables called in this script (like fips) are defined in a different script, as the dataset I'm working with is very large and I wanted to offload the startup time. But I don't think that's the issue?